# Reusing input validator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a logic for reusing multiple input validator at once. Here is DartPad code

```
void main() {

  String value = 'pppppp';

  print(InputValidator([InputValidator.minCharacters(value, 2),
                        InputValidator.maxCharacters(value, 5)
                        ]).validate().toString());
}

class InputValidator {
  final List<String> validators;

  InputValidator(this.validators);

  List<String> validate() {
    List<String> result = [];
    validators.where((s) => s != null).forEach(result.add);
    return result;
  }

  static String maxCharacters(String value, int limit) {
    if (value.length > limit) {
      return 'Max $limit characters allowed';
    }
    return null;
  }

  static String minCharacters(String value, int limit) {
    if (value.length < limit) {
      return 'Min $limit characters required';
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

the logic works great however I'm trying to make it even easier where I wouldn't need to pass value into each method. I want to make value parameter in InputValidator class and take that value when running a method. Problem is that each method is static so I can not use that parameter in method.. Is there any other way?

Here is how I would like to use it

```
validator: InputValidator(value, [InputValidator.minCharacters(2),
                                 InputValidator.maxCharacters(5)
                                 ]).validate()
```

Comment: how do you want to use it? `TextFormField(validator: ...` - what do you want to use instead of `...`?

Comment: if you convert to non static we can use cascade notation `..`

Comment: @delmin [reference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-) ,  i am trying out in dartpad now, will post if it works

Comment: I am asking what is the purpose? you want to have different min max ranges for text fields? like: `validator: limit(2, 5)` for example?

Comment: @pskink my goal is to make it as simple to use as possible. I've got many validators there for example to check if the input is correct email format, post code format and so on.. and I need to to mix them together in each TextField differently. So your solution `validator: limit(2, 5)` looks very nice. Can you share the code for it and can it be mixed by other validators?

Comment: `limit(min, max) {
  return (String s) => (min <= s.length && s.length <= max)? null : 'length not in range [$min..$max]';
}`

Comment: @pskink that looks great if I would only needed to validate min and max range.. I've got another 10 validators and I need to mix them together in each TextField differently .. That is why I created that class so when I will need them I don't have to write a lot of duplicate codes

Comment: so create another function that takes a list of validators as input and iterate over them calling each validator, something like: `validator: all([limit(2,5), uppercase()])`

Comment: @pskink hmm.. I don't know if I understand you correctly but it looks like that is exactly what I did in `validate()` method. To iterate through each one you need a value from the text field and parameters (min value...). So far I'm sending that value in each validator method separately and I was asking how to send the value only once into multiple valitadors

Comment: @pskink each method you have provided returning `FormFieldValidator` of type `String` . What exactly is `FormFieldValidator` Can you add it into your bin?

Comment: @pskink Thakns again.. I have already self answered my question but if you want to answer it I'll be more then happy to delete it and mark your answer as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once again thanks to @pskink where he pointed out on `FormFieldValidator`. With that it is very simple to reuse validating of TextFormField.

Here is validator class

```
    FormFieldValidator<String> all(Iterable validators) {
  return (String s) {
    var error = validators
      .map((v) => v(s))
      .where((error) => error != null)
      .join(' AND ');
    return error.isEmpty? null : error;
  };
}

 FormFieldValidator<String>  uppercase() {
  return (String s) => s.startsWith(RegExp('[A-Z]'))? null : 'does not start with uppercase' ;
}

 FormFieldValidator<String>  limit(min, max) {
  return (String s) => (min <= s.length && s.length <= max)? null : 'length not in range [$min..$max]';
}
```

and here how to use it

```
Column(
      children: [
        Form(key: _formKey, child: TextFormField(validator:all([limit(2,5), uppercase()]))),

        FlatButton(child:Text('Validate'), onPressed: (){if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) 
         {print('OK');}}),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: you dont need any class with static methods, flutter is full of top level functions - so you dont have to use `Validator.all` / `Validator.limit` etc

Comment: @pskink well that makes things even easier... Thanks again.. I have update my answer