# How to create a validation rule with mixed case and number in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

I want to create a validation rule in the [Flutter Validator](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation).
For reference, I want to create validator functions like the `mixedCase()` and `numbers()` [functions in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-passwords)

Roughly explained, something like this

1. Minimum 8 characters
2. A mixture of uppercase (A) and lowercase (a) letters
3. There must be at least 1 number

**Example**

```
Passwords1 = true;

passwords1 = false;

passwordss = false;
```

How to make this, is it possible?
I only know a few conditions right now in the `if-else` like:
`if (value == null || value.isEmpty)`
`if (value.length < 8)`

I also read some references like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57488523/9039350), but I don't understand the pattern of the (*for example*) `String patttern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';`

Can I write the rules as I want above into an `if-else` code block like this?

```
validator: (value) {
  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please fill the confirm password field';
  } else if (value != passwordController.text) {
    return 'Password doesn\'t match';
  }
  return null;
}
```

Please help or advice, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253787/how-to-handle-textfield-validation-in-password-in-flutter check this

Comment: check how `all` validator is implemented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62456818/2252830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `if-else` to do it but with a little trick, I already did it and here is my code:

```dart
// Create an enum containing warning information, you can modify your warning here
enum PasswordError {
  upperCase('Must contain at least one uppercase'),
  lowerCase('Must contain at least one lowercase'),
  digit('Must contain at least one digit'),
  eigthCharacter('Must be at least 8 characters in length'),
  specialCharacter('Contain at least one special character: !@#\\\$&*~');

  final String message;

  const PasswordError(this.message);
}

// Validate and return all errors as a List
//
// Here are the patterns and what it means:
// r'^
//   (?=.*?[A-Z])      // should contain at least one upper case
//   (?=.*?[a-z])      // should contain at least one lower case
//   (?=.*?[0-9])      // should contain at least one digit
//   (?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]) // should contain at least one Special character
//   .{8,}             // Must be at least 8 characters in length
// $
//
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253787/how-to-handle-textfield-validation-in-password-in-flutter
List<PasswordError> passwordValidator(String password) {
  List<PasswordError> errors = [];
  if (!RegExp(r'[A-Z]').hasMatch(password)) {
    errors.add(PasswordError.upperCase);
  }
  if (!RegExp(r'[a-z]').hasMatch(password)) {
    errors.add(PasswordError.lowerCase);
  }
  if (!RegExp(r'[0-9]').hasMatch(password)) {
    errors.add(PasswordError.digit);
  }
  if (!RegExp(r'[!@#\$&*~]').hasMatch(password)) {
    errors.add(PasswordError.specialCharacter);
  }
  if (!RegExp(r'.{8,}').hasMatch(password)) {
    errors.add(PasswordError.eigthCharacter);
  }

  return errors;
}
```

Then you can use it for validator:

```dart
validator: (password) {
  if (password != null) {
    // Get all errors
    final validators = passwordValidator(password);

    // Returns null if password is valid
    if (validators.isEmpty) return null;
     
    // Join all errors that start with "-"
    return validators
        .map((e) => '- ${e.message}')
        .join('\n');
  }

  return null;
},
```

Comment: Umm, where should I write the code for `enum PasswordError` and `List<PasswordError> passwordValidator(String password)` part? Sorry, I'm still a beginner..

Comment: Never mind, i created file inside `Lib > Helpers` name `PasswordValidate.dart`, and call it inside my sign up forms. This is the right way right?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Yes, that's right. And you can store it anywhere.

Comment: Okay, which is the best or better way? I'm just confused to make a RegExp pattern where in the answer it is only provided for Uppercase and limit, while in my case more conditions are needed..

Comment: @pskink No no, I already understand, and in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453648/reusing-input-validator/62456818#62456818) I've also upvoted.. I understand from the code, but I think the answer above is easier to understand. Now my question is, which one is better? Is there any difference using `enum` as you said?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal I think no one is better than another, you just need to use which one is easier for you to understand and modify when you need to. You don't need to use `enum` in my code as well, the `enum` that I created makes it easier for me to change the message (multi-languages) because it just stores in that `enum`.